# Add link on course page depending on course custom field

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, moodle

I am using **Moodle 2.7** and have the following **custom field** for the **courses** in the database table `mdl_course_info_field`:

> Full name: School course
>
> Shrot name: school
>
> Type: Menu of choices
>
> Choices:
>
> - Highschool course
> - Prepschool course

The target was to show the link on every course page, where under the settings the **chechbox** for **Highschool course** is used. In the file `mymoodle/local/link/functions.js` there is the **link**:

```
if($('#page-course-view-topcollmytheme .orangebar p')) {
    $('#page-course-view-topcollmytheme #section-0 .content > .summary').append('<button class="highschoollink">Hig school course</button>');
}
```

How to check, **if** the checkbox is choosen an **then** to show the link on the course page?

Comment: Where do you want to display the field? In the course header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a renderer to display a course header:

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-36048

So you could include the school link in the course header - here is an example:

In `/course/format/formatname/lib.php`

Add this function to `class format_formatname`

```
/**
 * Display's a header at the top of the sections.
 *
 * @return renderable class
 */
public function course_content_header() {
    global $DB, $PAGE, $USER;

    if (!isset($PAGE)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Only display if we are on the course-view page.
    if (strpos($PAGE->pagetype, 'course-view-') !== 0) {
        return null;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT d.data
            FROM {course_info_field} f
            JOIN {course_info_data} d ON d.fieldid = f.id AND d.courseid = :courseid
            WHERE f.shortname = :shortname";
    $params = array('courseid' => $this->courseid, 'shortname' => 'school');
    $schoolname = $DB->get_field_sql($sql, $params);
    $schoolurl = '';
    // You should store the school url in the database somewhere.
    // Using switch code for this example.
    switch ($schoolname) {
        case 'high school' :
            $schoolurl = new moodle_url('http://www.schoolsite.com');
            break;
        ...
    }

    return new format_formatname_coursecontentheader($schoolname, $schoolurl);
}
```

Also add this class to `/course/format/formatname/lib.php`

```
class format_formatname_coursecontentheader implements renderable {
    /**
     * School name
     *
     * @var string $schoolname
     */
    public $schoolname;

    /**
     * School url
     *
     * @var string $schoolurl
     */
    public $schoolurl;

    /**
     * Class storing information to be passed and displayed in the course content header
     *
     * @param string $schoolname
     * @param moodle_url $schoolurl
     */
    public function __construct($schoolname, $schoolurl) {
        $this->schoolname = $schoolname;
        $this->schoolurl = $fields->schoolurl;
    }
}
```

Then in `/course/format/formatname/renderer.php`

Add this function to `class format_formatname_renderer`

```
/**
 * Renders course header
 *
 * @param renderable $courseheader
 * @return string
 */
public function render_format_formatname_coursecontentheader($courseheader) {
    $output = '';

    $schoolname = $courseheader->schoolname;
    $schoolurl = $courseheader->schoolurl;

    $link = html_writer::link($schoolurl, $schoolname);

    $output .= html_writer::div($link, 'format-formatname-schoollink');

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the link to the course as a URL resource.

Then make sure 'conditional activities' are enabled for the site.

Finally edit the URL activity to restrict access to users who have the correct user profile field.

See https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Conditional_activities_settings for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but it is not als URL activity, but in the code in the functions.js. My questions was, how the get the `high school course` customfield and depending on it to show the link? It is not user custom field, but course custom field and "school" with param1 "Highschool course".